# How to overwrite files on Ubuntu? mv -f/--force doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, mv

[image]

Here is my error, yes, this folder already contains such files but it needs to be updated every time, how can I solve that problem ? Have tried `rsync -a` also couple of code examples from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269775/mv-directory-not-empty) but unsuccessfully, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, can u help me, guys ?

That's an Ubuntu from GitLab pipeline (Docker image)

Answer (score 0):

mv command is used to move existing file or directory from one location to another and for renaming file in the same directory! You should use cp command to overwrite files.

Comment: tried to do cp also, but it does no effect, files are not updated